# Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class

Tags: java, database, oracle, connection, hashtable

Database connection. There is more than one way to solve this problem that i know of, but i always get these failures.

There is this `java.naming.factory.internal` thing that wants to instantiate the `oracle.aurora.jndi.ojds.OjdsInternalContentFactory` and this is the failure:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: oracle.aurora.jndi.ojds.OjdsInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.aurora.jndi.ojds.OjdsInitialContextFactory]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at DB.DBConnector.OpenConnection(DBConnector.java:32)
    at DB.DBConnector.OpenConnection(DBConnector.java:48)
    at DB.Start.main(Start.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.aurora.jndi.ojds.OjdsInitialContextFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:672)
    ... 6 more
```

---

And here is my Program:

---

```
package DB;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.*;
import javax.sql.DataSource;


public class DBConnector 
{
       private String username;
       private String password;
       Connection con = null;


       public void setUsername(String u)
       {
           username=u;
       }
       public void setPassword(String p)
       {
           password=p;
       }

       public Connection OpenConnection() throws Exception
       {
           Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
           env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "oracle.aurora.jndi.ojds.OjdsInitialContextFactory");
           env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"ojds://thin:VAULAB2:1521:TLMSMP");

           Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
            try
            {
              DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx; //new InitialContext().lookup( "DBconfig" );
              con = ds.getConnection(username,password);
              return con;             
            }
            finally
            {

            }
       }
       public Connection OpenConnection(String u, String p) throws Exception
       {
              username=u;
              password=p;
              return OpenConnection();
       }
       public void CloseConnection() throws Exception
       {
           if ( con != null )
                try { con.close(); } catch ( SQLException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
       }

       public DBConnector()
       {

       }
       public DBConnector(String _username,String _password)
       {
           setUsername(username);
           setPassword(password);
       }
```

---

Comment: 'Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.aurora.jndi.ojds.OjdsInitialContextFactory'.

Please check the jar containing oracle.aurora.jndi.ojds.OjdsInitialContextFactory is in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

this

ClassNotFoundException: oracle.aurora.jndi.ojds.OjdsInitialContextFactory

is your problem, the class cannot be found on the classpath, so you need to install the library it comes in.

Comment: where can i find this library?

Comment: Find the docs @ http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/jndi_support.htm#CHDDCCEE